# Change height element on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-chosen

I have a user-friendly multiple select created using [**jQuery Chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select). The height of the multiple select container div increases when selecting multiple elements. I want to keep this height only if the container div is on focus. But if is not on focus get a fixed height.

if on focus (height:auto):
[image]

else (height:40px):
[image]

This is what I did:

```
$('.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices').live('focus',function(){
    var autoHeight = $(this).css('height', 'auto').height();
    $(this).height(40).animate({height:autoHeight},300);
}).live('blur',function(){
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).animate({height:50},300);
    }
});
```

This works fine but i can't select all elements. What did I do wrong?
 
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fHABD/)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: for starters... `live` is deprecated. Use `on`.

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.3, and `.live()` works fine. The issue is that when i click on the `div.chosen-drop` to select an option the above div that contains the selected options doesn't animate the height correcly, because the focus is specified only for this div.

Comment: I have to get the focus method to both divs. But i don't know how.. i tried with `$('.chosen-choices, .chosen-drop').live('focus'` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
$('.chosen-container-multi').live('focus', function(event) {   
    var select = $('.chosen-container-multi').find(".chosen-choices");
    var curHeight =  select.height();
    var autoHeight = select.height();

    curHeight = select.height();
    autoHeight = select.css('height', 'auto').height();
    select.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 300);

    event.stopPropagation();
}).live('blur',function(){
    $('.chosen-container-multi').find(".chosen-choices").animate({height: 30}, 300);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fHABD/6/)

But when I select an option the height is animated to 30px and then returns auto (to see select more than two elements). how do I prevent this behavior?